Would I fork or clone a repository to get my copy of a repo only to look at?

I want to have my own copy of a Git repository to b able to set up and run the project on my machine.
I only want to look at it, run it and debug/trace through it.
I will not make any changes to my or the original repository.
I do not want to push anything to the original repo

To get my own copy of the project: Do I clone or fork the original repository?

Clone is just for making local copy of repository.
Fork - is clone + your own github repository.
So for your case clone is enough
